# Removing route element in .net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

What is the way to remove this route from the routecollection ? I have modular system and one module needs to override the route but when I write a new route with same name, it says

***A route named 'HomePage' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.
Parameter name: name***

```
        //home page
        routes.MapLocalizedRoute("HomePage",
                        "",
                        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
                        new[] { "Test.Web.Controllers" });
```

This is module

***So first I need to remove HomePage route if it exists and add new one like below ? But I dont know how to remove it**

```
        routes.MapLocalizedRoute("HomePage",
                        "",
                        new { controller = "TwoStepCheckout", action = "Index" },
                        new[] { "Test.Plugin.TwoStepCheckout" });
```

Comment: Are you sure you just don't want to give YOUR route a different name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove it by doing:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Remove(RouteTable.Routes["HomePage"]);
```